# Function of insulation monitoring devices: Why are the test currents coupled with high resistances instead of inductivities?

Tags: inductor

I learned that insulation monitoring devices work by connecting a small DC voltage source to two or more phases of an IT power grid and measuring the leakage current over a dedicated shunt.

The coupling to the phases is done over relatively high resistors resulting in a very small current to measure inside the insulation monitoring device. The purpose of the high so called coupling resistors is to keep the power grid's energy out of the monitoring device in case of a hard short to protective earth.

I'm wondering why one doesn't use high impedance inductors for coupling to the phases of the grid. In my opinion a very high inductance will limit the current caused by a hard short as well while keeping the DC impedance very low for a better detection of reduced insulation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ4mCh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My simplified schematic shows my current understanding of such devices. The two bulbs are only resembling some arbitrary load in an IT grid. The interesting part of the setup is the fault resistor resembling some insulation gone bad and establishing an unwanted connection to protective earth.
The dashed box denotes the parts of the monitoring device. The RCs inside are the coupling resistors which are high enough to prevent detrimental currents through the monitoring device in case of a hard short (i.e. R_fault=0 Ω). For a 230/400 V grid I think RC might be in the MΩ range. Rm is likely one or two orders of magnitude below RC to keep the voltage of the differential amplifier (greatly simplified again) within usable limits. However given a typical measurement voltage of 10V might yield only 10 μA for a hard short (R_fault=0 Ω) and perhaps 5 μA for an acceptable insulation resistance (typically R_fault > 1 MΩ). This is a rather small range at a rather small signal.

If one replaced RC by a very high inductor, the current through the monitoring device in case of a hard short will be limited to a arbitrary small value while the measurement curent would depend only on Vtest, RM and R_fault. In my opinion this can increase the sensitivity at low cost.

An example of a typical circuit in a monitoring device can be found in this patend: EP2256506B1. Of course, the mechanism suggested in this invention can't use inductors, because it uses modulated voltages for detection to enable insulation fault detection even in DC grids. However I couldn't find any referenced invention using a circuit which differs greatly from the approach I tried to sketch here.

There must be some reason not to use inductors here. Do you know some?

Comment: Designer of that system may have a few reasons to do it this way. Most of things can be done different ways for optimization and many factors may affect the final decision. For instance: cost, elements availability, designer habits, etc.

Comment: Measuring on R_shunt is very precise and with fast response so it is suitable for fault detection. Measuring on current transformers has slower response, less precision but the big advantage is they are less lossy, so they can be used as series element for measuring high currents.

Comment: Resistors are cheap and light, inductors are expensive, big and heavy, for the same high voltage withstanding.

Comment: @user263983 I do not doubt that the designers have reasons for their decisions. That's the core of my question here. I want to know the reasons. :)

Comment: @Ariser What is the role of V1 (10 V) on the schematic?

Comment: @Karlsson V1 is the test voltage. It will elicit a measurable fault current if isolation is weakened at some point.

Comment: @Ariser Ok - sounds familiar... Is it something like a sinusoidal test voltage similar to the one which we have in the classic LCR meter, which allows us to measure impedance of the component or circuit at its terminals? (assuming, of course, that R_Fault is simply a side effect of insulation degradation and not an actual component measured by LCR meter.

Comment: @Karlsson I think the test voltage is basically a DC voltage, sometimes a pulsed DC voltage, so it can be tracked with additional sensing hardware. This enables it to find the branch with weak insulation more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The RCs inside are the coupling resistors which are high enough to
> prevent detrimental currents through the monitoring device in case of
> a hard short (i.e. R_fault=0 Ω). For a 230/400 V grid I think RC might
> be in the MΩ range.*

Then, your inductors probably need to be of the same reactive value. At 50 Hz, this means an inductance of over three thousand henries. Have you ever come across anything that big (in value and certainly in size)?

> *There must be some reason not to use inductors here. Do you know some?*

They'll be expensive and large and, potentially, they'll produce a back-emf when disconnecting from the system that could cause a serious jolt to the user.

Comment: Fun fact: I looked up high inductivities, the biggest I found at first glance was 10 H. This „power inductor“ already has a series resistance of 500 Ω. So even if scaled up 300 times the series resistance will reach values in the same order of magnitude I wanted to replace initially. So this perfectly prooves your answer, as there is no benefit whatsoever. Coils don't scale well other than capacitors.

Comment: Another fun fact - if you stretched a wire from the earth to the moon, it's self inductance would still only be about 500 henries.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, Resistors are used instead of inductors (my guess) because inductors can act as antennas (transformers) and "send" power over a distance that the insulation would not stop (unless you use EMI shielded wires but those are not even 100% effective).

Comment: I'm not sure if your answer addresses my question fully. The insulation under scrutiny is in most cases many metres if not hundreds away from the monitoring device. In most cases the monitoring device is mounted at the bus bar of a distribution box or a feed line branching from a bus bar. I think it should be possible to shield the monitoring device sufficiently.